# Apache MINA FTP Server: How to set the log level for the FtpLoggingFilter

Tags: apache, logging, ftp

I am wondering how I can adjust the log levels for some message types in the FtpLoggingFilter when using the Apache FTP Server from the MINA project. In particular, I would like the following to have log level DEBUG:

- sessionCreatedLevel
- sessionOpenedLevel
- sessionIdleLevel
- sessionClosedLevel

I had a look around the code, but didn't find out how I can directly access the FtpLoggingFilter instance via some of the FTP classes I am using (Listener, ListenerFactory, FtpServer, FtpServerFactory…). It seems to me that the logging config is hidden deeply inside the class structure and can't be modified. 
Is this assumption correct or how can I modify the log levels?

Thanks a lot.

Cheers,

Martin

Answer (score 0):

By looking into the source code of *org.apache.ftpserver.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter* I found it is using SLF4J. So it depends on which logging implementation your installation uses.

Assuming it is *java.util.logging* one could set another logging level like this

```
    java.util.logging.Logger jul = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.ftpserver.listener.nio.FtpLoggingFilter");
    jul.setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE);
```

Comment: it is interesting, where we should call this set level. Right now doesn't work for me...